# QTableWidget, cellClicked and cellDoubleClicked

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with row selection, and i'm trying to treat 3 signals:

- cellClicked
- cellDoubleClicked
- customContextMenuRequested

Things seem to be fine in code: i had in mind the connect syntax, type params are correct and match, etc; and to be more specific, i "know" that the code is correct because i have the following situation:

- if i connect the 3 signals to their respective slots, only the single click and the context menú work.
- if i connect just one signal each time i compile the code and i run the program, that signal is working well (for the 3 of them).
- if i connect the single click signal and the context menu, commenting the connect macro for the double click, they work well. Same for double click and context menu.

BUT if i connect the single click and the double click, the double click is not being treated by my custom slot.

Just to clarify, each signal has a different slot, and as i meantioned above, they work well if i just connect one of them and comment the other 2 in code.

So my question is:
 is there any bug with the cellClicked and cellDoubleClick working simultaneously? do i have to set some flag, attribute or whatever that belongs to the QTableWidget?

I'm running out of ideas, thanks for the help!

And also, maybe the code should help:

table and slots declaration:

```
QTableWidget * table;

public slots:
  void tableChange(int row, int column);
  void tableChangeDbl(int row, int column);
  void PopupMenuTableShow(const QPoint &);
```

the connects:

```
  connect(table, SIGNAL(cellDoubleClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(tableChangeDbl(int, int)));
  connect(table, SIGNAL(cellClicked(int, int)), this, SLOT(tableChange(int, int)));
  connect(table, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(PopupMenuTableShow(const QPoint &)));
```

Comment: It would be useful showing what you do in each slot ( mainly single click. Imagine that youre showing a MessageBox on click, widget loses focus and double click is never fired ...)

Comment: Ok Trompa, i think you nailed it. I commented the code inside the slots and only left debug traces, and it's working. In fact i cannot show here the code because is a big net of components and business logics and so on, so definitly i will have to go deep inside to see who is taking the focus (for example, if i click, one of things i perform is to disable and enable some group of actions, so maybe is something like that). I will try to find it and to solve it, and then i'll update here the result. Thank you!